# How to make a node result be different depending on the existence of a certain node using XLST?

Tags: xml, xslt

My system produces a XML that contain a node that, depending on the type of event, came with different name.
The name can be `<floatRate>` or `<fixedRate>`. The path is always the same, only the node name that is different.

I need a transformation that can populate one field based on that name. The field will be called `<type>` and the contend must be float or fixed, based on the node name.
Can this be done?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution that follows the spirit of XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fixedRate|floatRate">
   <type><xsl:value-of select=
           "substring-before(name(),'Rate')"/></type>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<rates>
    <fixedRate>2.3</fixedRate>
    <floatRate>1.1</floatRate>
</rates>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<rates>
   <type>fixed</type>
   <type>float</type>
</rates>
```

Comment: I believe i'll use something like this. Tanks again Dimitre.

Answer (score 0):

Select/mach expressions can do boolean "or", as in

```
match="floatRate|fixedRate"
```

Edit your question and add samples of input, expected output and what you've already tried to get more help

Comment: I didn't realize that select/mach expressions can do boolean (or union). More, that this is the simpliest way to do what i need.
Tanks for the help. With this and the examples that the other give, i believe i find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have this document as input:

```
<result>
    <floatRate>1.1</floatRate>
</result>
```

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="result">
        <type>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(name(floatRate|fixedRate),'Rate')"/>
        </type>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<type>float</type>
```

Comment: I don't get the need for the <xsl:template match="text()"/> expression. What is it for?

Comment: @Daniel Corsi: That template overwrite built-in template for text nodes (just output its value). In this case, is not really necessary: `result` template breaks the recursion before reaching the text node of `floatRate`.